# when using ajax to load a view component the view components javaScript Codes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

i used a view Component that has some javaScript codes for animations.
when page loaded javaScript works well but when click a button to load data with ajax,
data loaded correctly but javaScript codes doesn't work any more

// in view component code

```
   public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(GalleryInvokeParameterViewModel par)
    {
    var gallery = await _productService.GetGalleriesForSingleProductAsync(par.ProductID,par.ColorID);
    ViewBag.mainImage = await _productService.GetMainImageGalleryForSingleProductAsync(par.ProductID, par.ColorID);
    ViewBag.productId = par.ProductID;
    return View("SingleProductGallery",gallery);
    }
```

// in controller

```
    public IActionResult ChangeGallery(int id, int colorId)
{
var parameters = new GalleryInvokeParameterViewModel
{
ColorID = colorId,
ProductID = id
};
return ViewComponent("SingleProductGallery", parameters);
}
```

// in javascript codes for ZOOM image ON HOVER IMAGE
// these codes doesn't work after calling ajax to load data

```
    var zoomArea = document.getElementById("zoom-area");
var zoomImage = document.getElementById("zoom-image");
zoomArea.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
var clientX = event.clientX - zoomArea.offsetLeft;
var clientY = event.clientY - zoomArea.offsetTop;
var aWidth = zoomArea.offsetWidth;
var aHeight = zoomArea.offsetHeight;
clientX = (clientX / aWidth) * 100;
clientY = (clientY / aHeight) * 100;
zoomImage.style.transform =
"translate(-" + clientX + "% , -" + clientY + "%) scale(1.5)";
});
$(zoomArea).mouseleave(function () {
zoomImage.style.transform = "translate(-50% , -50%) scale(1)";
});
```

Comment: `data loaded correctly but javascript is disabled`Do you mean `$("#product-gallery").html(res);` doesn't work?Do you have any error in console?

Comment: I may be missing something, but where are you calling your JS function `getGallery(id, colorId)`?

Comment: @YiyiYou no there isn't any error. before calling ajax, all of functions that used for ui and animations for elements work well and there isn't any error in console. but when i click a button to load data with ajax in view component , data loaded but the javascripts code for ui and animations dosen't work.

Comment: @MatthewM. in input onclick event

Comment: ` when page loaded javaScript works well but when click a button to load data with ajax`Can you show more about your ajax and  the  button?

Comment: @Yiyi You , i found a solution.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution for this issue.
after ajax called and returned data i call :

```
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {js code});
```

and it reloaded javaScript codes again and my animations code works well.